In Delphi Components Creation, who controls the ComponentState Property?
I'm writing a little wrapper of AlmediaDev's TscPanel and GlyphIcons to create a behavior similar to TLabeledEdit. Once the component is added in design time I wanted to check 3 conditions:

If it's design time (via csDesigning in ComponentState)
If the owner is a TForm (i.e it's not being added into another panel or smth).
If the TscStyledForm is already on that form and has the property of shadowing activated.

My problem arises from the fact that my ComponentState seems to be empty, what makes me think on who manages, adding or removing flags, this property. Since it's inherited from TComponent all the way up I don't believe it is managed by the third-party.
As a side question, am I able to access other components from the form and change their properties on design time? Like in my 3rd condition, if it's not active couldn't I activate it myself?
Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 Added the code I use to retrieve my ComponentState
constructor TImprovedFluentTopBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

  ShowMessage('Creating');
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then     // Pesquisar sobre isso aqui
  begin
    ShowMessage('Checking');
    if not (AOwner is TForm) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Owner must be a TForm.');
    end;

    var Found: Boolean := False;
    for var I:Integer := 0 to TForm(AOwner).ComponentCount - 1 do   // Cast de AOwner para TForm. Acessa a componentCount do TForm.
    begin
      if TForm(AOwner).Components[I] is TImprovedFluentTopBar then
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('TImprovedFluentTopBar is already on the form.');
      end
      else if TForm(AOwner).Components[I] is TscStyledForm then
      begin
        Found := True;
      end;
    end;

    if not Found then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('TscStyleControls not found in current TForm');
    end;
  end else begin
     ShowMessage(ComponentStateAsString(ComponentState));
  end;

  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Self.Caption := '';
  Self.DragForm := True;
  FCloseButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FCloseButton.Align := alRight;
  FCloseButton.SetBounds(20, 60, 20, 20);
  FMinimizeButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FMinimizeButton.Align := alRight;
  FMinimizeButton.SetBounds(20, 20, 20, 20);
end;

and the ComponentStateAsString:
function ComponentStateAsString(ACS: TComponentState): String;
begin
  Result := 'States: ';
  if (csAncestor in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csAncestor ';
  end;

  if (csDesigning in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csDesigning ';
  end;

  if (csDestroying in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csDestroying ';
  end;

  if (csFixups in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csFixups ';
  end;

  if (csFreeNotification in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csFreeNotification ';
  end;

  if (csInline in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csInline ';
  end;

  if (csLoading in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csLoading ';
  end;

  if (csReading in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csReading ';
  end;

  if (csWriting in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csWriting ';
  end;

  if (csDesignInstance in ACS) then
  begin
    Result := Result + 'csDesignInstance ';
  end;


end;



My problem arises from the fact that my ComponentState seems to be empty, what makes me think on who manages, adding or removing flags, this property.

The csDesigning flag is added to or removed from your component's ComponentState property by the TComponent.SetDesigning() method, which is called by TComponent.InsertComponent() when your component is added to an Owner component who already has the csDesigning flag (which the Form Designer does).  Your component's inherited constructor calls InsertComponent() if the AOwner parameter is not nil:
constructor TComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ...
  if AOwner <> nil then AOwner.InsertComponent(Self);
end;

procedure TComponent.InsertComponent(const AComponent: TComponent);
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    AComponent.SetDesigning(True);
  ...
end;

procedure TComponent.SetDesigning(Value, SetChildren: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Value then
    Include(FComponentState, csDesigning) else
    Exclude(FComponentState, csDesigning);
  if SetChildren then
    for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do Components[I].SetDesigning(Value);
end;

As such, your component's constructor should call the inherited constructor BEFORE reading the ComponentState property.  But, you are calling inherited AFTER reading the ComponentState, which is why you are not seeing the csDesigning flag assigned yet:
constructor TImprovedFluentTopBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner); // <-- DO THIS FIRST!

  ShowMessage('Creating');
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  begin
    ...
  end;

  //inherited Create(AOwner); // <-- NOT HERE!
  ...
end;

If you don't want to call inherited sooner, then you will have to check for the csDesigning flag in the AOwner.ComponentState property instead:
constructor TImprovedFluentTopBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

  ShowMessage('Creating');
  if (AOwner <> nil) and (csDesigning in AOwner.ComponentState) then
  begin
    ...
  end;

  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...
end;


Read some sources and your answer gave me a click. I'm raising exceptions if the checks fail so there would be of any problem calling the inherited before. As a bonus, learned there's a way to access owner's state. Thank you :)
